# Save images from url with variable

Tags: php, digit, ddos, save-image

**After your help, many stackoverflow posts, the solution is at the bottom of this post as an UPDATE.**

I am trying to save some images automatically using this code in a php file :

```
for ($num1=100;$num1<999;$num1++)
{
    for ($num2=100;$num2<999;$num2++)
    {
        $postURL = "http://link_00000'.$num1.'_'.$num2.'.jpg";
        $ch = curl_init('http://link_00000'.$num1.'_'.$num2.'.jpg');
        $fp = fopen($postURL, '/path/Apolo/img/'.$num1.'_'.$num2.'.jpg', 'wb');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

> First question :

`$num1` and `$num2` should start from 000 to 999 and not from 0 to 999. Putting more `$num` variables (`$num3`, `$num4` ...) would be a solution but I presume there is a better one for the digits.

> Second question :

The images are not saved. I tried this one as well but it did not work:

`copy($postURL, '/path/img/'.$num1.'_'.$num2.'.jpg');`

> Third question :

How can I prevent an action like d-dos attack? If I load the links without a time delay, probably the website will be down.

---

UPD:

```
for ($num1=000;$num1<999;$num1++)
{
    for ($num2=000;$num2<999;$num2++)
    {
        $url = 'http://link.com/00000'.sprintf("%03d", $num1).'_'.sprintf("%03d", $num2).'.jpg';
        echo ''.$num1.'_'.$num2.'';
        echo "\n";
        if (@getimagesize($url)) \\ checks if url-image exists
        {   
            echo $url;
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            $fp = fopen('/path/Apolo/00000'.sprintf("%03d", $num1).'_'.sprintf("%03d", $num2).'.jpg', 'wb'); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
            curl_exec($ch); 
            curl_close($ch); 
            fclose($fp);
            sleep(1); //1 second delay to avoid d-dos
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: look at the examples how to deal with a for loop: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: You are concatenating wrongly the variables in the value of `$postURL`. Try using single quotes as string delimiters instead of double.

Comment: Why did you end up using the solution with a lot of for loops and nums instead of just using `sprintf("%03d", $num1)` that automatically adds your leading zeroes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are dealing with integers you cannot say 000, as that is equal to 0, if you want it to write 000, then you should use a string instead.

In your example you are looping through the numbers, so writing it as strings would be messy if you wan't to loop it. 
 
Therefor the best solution would be to just add the leading 0's yourself, this can be done like this:
`sprintf("%03d", $num1);`

This will automatically add the leadings zeroes, that you wanted.

UPDATE 1: (forgot to answer the save image)

For saving the images you can do it like this:
`file_put_contents('/path/Apolo/img/filename'.sprintf("%03d", $num1).'_'.sprintf("%03d", $num2).'.jpg', file_get_contents($postURL));`

Update 2: (code example):

```
for ($num1=100;$num1<999;$num1++)
    for ($num2=100;$num2<999;$num2++){
        $postURL = 'http://link_00000'.sprintf("%03d", $num1).'_'.sprintf("%03d", $num2).'.jpg';
        $path = '/path/Apolo/img/filename'.sprintf("%03d", $num1).'_'.sprintf("%03d", $num2).'.jpg';
        file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($postURL));
}
```

Question 3:

There at lots of ways to prevent DDOS attacks, but if you just wan't your site to run quickly and prevent/handle DDOS attacks then change your DNS to cloudflare, it's worth it and their free account is more then enough for you.

Comment: I can save the image with my code when I am not using variables. Also, I am using an IF with (@getimagesize($url)) before. This one is not working. Do I have to load a library before?

Comment: getimagesize needs to have a full url including 'http://'. With this one it works.

Comment: Sorry I wrote something wrong in `file_put_contents` I forgot to add the complete filename. Just updated my post

Comment: @ApoloRadomer: do you need the size of the image too?

Comment: It works now. I used imagesize to check if the image exists. So, I would not have dumb in my saved folder. 

I am using sleep(1) to avoid a 'd-dos' attack as well.

Comment: Makes sense, well `sleep(1)`doesn't prevent DDOS at all, it can just help you minimize your resource usage at once in this example.

Comment: I am going to load hundreds/thouasnds of links. If I have an one second gap (1), I guess there won't be any problem. It is like the website traffic is big. Also, note that (2), some of the links do not exist. Although, they are still requests from the domain, so I guess it is the same thing. It does not matter if the link exists or not. Right?

Comment: Yes you will still need to make a request to the domain first, so it still uses resources, but it will use less resources as it doesn't need to save the image then.

Comment: Also, do I have to use 'unsleep' after 'sleep'? I was about to use the 'wait' instead.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer, pretty sure that there are nothing in php called `unsleep`, you can choose between `sleep` and ´usleep`, the difference is that `usleep` is in microseconds and `sleep` is in seconds.

Comment: @uruloke +1 nice info